# How to organize images in Gridpane?

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

```
if(list != null){
        for(File file : list){
            //Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
            final Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(file), 150, 0, true,true);
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            imageView = createImageView(image);

            VBox vb = new VBox();
            vb.getChildren().addAll(imageView);

            grid.add(vb, imageCol, imageRow);
            GridPane.setMargin(imageView, new Insets(50, 50, 50, 50));

            imageCol++;

            if(imageCol > 1){
                imageCol = 0;
                imageRow++;
            }
        }
    }
```

> Function to display images on a gridpane.

```
public void GridPaneThumbnail(){
     grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
     grid.setPadding(new Insets(100, 100, 100, 100));

     grid.setHgap(300);
     grid.setVgap(200);


     ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
     columnConstraints.setFillWidth(true);
     columnConstraints.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
     grid.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
}
```

> GridPane settings

I would like to know how do I display Images that are in ImageView in GridPane, to be shown as a list or a medium icon sized, as the current image shown is in large size.

GridPaneThumbnail() is initialized at the beginning.

This is how it looks like currently,

[image: current sample]

Comment: You just want to change the size of the images that are displayed?

Comment: If possible I'd like to display them as a list that shows the name, date & type of file (.jpg/.png)

Comment: Either just add labels to your grid pane with the appropriate information, or use a [`ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html)